# awesomium control isn't visiting google

Tags: c#, awesomium, document-ready

Hy all,

I'm making an Winform project with an awesomium webcontrol inside an class. I'm navigating that controll to `http://www.google.com/` ( just for the test ) and added an `DocumentReady` even listner to it. But it won't fire the listener... ( `i don't get the "in the listener!" message`)

Here's the code i've got ( i call the `doSomeScrap` in the main form (`Form1`):

```
class scrapper
{
    WebControl web = new WebControl();

    public void doSomeScrap()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("in the scrapper...");
        web.DocumentReady += webcontrolEventListener;
        web.Source = "http://www.google.com".ToUri();
        web.Update();
    }

    private void webcontrolEventListener(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("in the listener!");
    }
}
```

Also, I've heard of `LoadingFrameCompleted`, but when i use that, i get the following error:

```
'Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl' does not contain a definition for 'LoadingFrameCompleted' and no extension method 'LoadingFrameCompleted' accepting a first argument of type 'Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So what did i do wrong? Or what did i forget to make this work?

**Extra Info:**
I've got another webcontrol in the form gui, and when i use this code on it ( without the `update()` call, the controll is navigating... So my guys is that it isn't navigating because it isn't in the GUI. But how can i make it navigate then?

Comment: Try it with another site, at least you will know if it's a problem in your code or not. Google has mechanisms in place to prevent being scraped.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella, Nope, other sites doesn't work either ( `tested: www.reddit.com, www.tweakers.net, www.nu.nl` )

Comment: Is it actually making the call to the web site? You can check with Fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars, thanks for the link! I've looked and it looks like it doesn't make any connection at all...

Comment: `Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl` sounds like Winforms to me, not WPF.

Comment: @swandog, your totaly right. I've mixed them up... Changed that in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need to display the page being scraped to the user, I would perform web-scraping using a non-Windowed WebView that can execute on a background thread.

### Example of scraping in a non-windowed console app

```cs
// Credit: Awesomium v1.7.2 C# Basic Sample
//         by Perikles C. Stephanidis
using System;
using Awesomium.Core;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BasicSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            WebCore.Initialize(WebConfig.Default);

            Uri url = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

            using ( WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(WebPreferences.Default) )
            {
                // WebView implements IDisposable. Here we demonstrate
                // wrapping it in a using statement.
                using ( WebView view = WebCore.CreateWebView( 1100, 600, session ) )
                {
                    bool finishedLoading = false;
                    bool finishedResizing = false;

                    Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Loading: {0} ...", url ) );

                    // Load a URL.
                    view.Source = url;

                    // This event is fired when a frame in the
                    // page finished loading.
                    view.LoadingFrameComplete += ( s, e ) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Frame Loaded: {0}", e.FrameId ) );

                        // The main frame usually finishes loading last for a given page load.
                        if ( e.IsMainFrame )
                            finishedLoading = true;
                    };

                    while ( !finishedLoading )
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep( 100 );
                        // A Console application does not have a synchronization
                        // context, thus auto-update won't be enabled on WebCore.
                        // We need to manually call Update here.
                        WebCore.Update();
                    }

                    // Print some more information.
                    Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Page Title: {0}", view.Title ) );
                    Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Loaded URL: {0}", view.Source ) );
                } // Destroy and dispose the view.
            } // Release and dispose the session.            

            // Shut down Awesomium before exiting.
            WebCore.Shutdown();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

### Example of a working scraper using a windowed control

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public partial class DemoForm : Form
    {
        private Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl web;

        public DemoForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            doSomeScrap();
        }

        public void doSomeScrap()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("in the scrapper...");
            web.DocumentReady += webcontrolEventListener;
            web.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
            web.Update();
        }

        private void webcontrolEventListener(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("in the listener!");
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.web = new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl();
            this.web.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(this.web);

            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
            this.Name = "DemoForm";
            this.Text = "DemoForm";

            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As swandog mentioned, the project isn't an wpf but an winform application. I made a mistake at that 1.

And the user doesn't see the page i'm scrapping from, so i'm trying to use the non windowed version of awesomium.

I'll take a look at the code you provided and come back with more info...

Comment: @Mathlight - sorry SO hid your comment by default, so I missed it.  Updated my answer to remove the WPF comments...

Comment: Alright, no problem. I'm trying to implement the `Example of scraping in a non-windowed console app` code into my `scrapper` class, but i think that i don't understand it at all...

Could you help me a little more? I'm very new to this type of programming...

Comment: The non-windowed sample is a simple console (command line) app.  The entry point to a command line app in C# is the `static void Main` method.  The app polls the `finishedLoading` boolean, sleeping the execution thread until this boolean is true.  The boolean is initialized as false, then set to true in the event handler for the webview's `LoadingFrameComplete` event.

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Been struggling with this for days now and it's finally working! I'll reward the bounty in 20 hours. Thanks!

Comment: LOL, thanks!  Awesomium is a pretty complex API to learn, so hang in there.  Good luck!

Comment: Eeeuhm, i agree with that, but it pretty nice to :D. But I've got an problem... I'm having this weird issue: When i press an button that calls the scrapper, it's "scrapping", but when i'm navigating in an webcontrol in the gui, ánd then call the scrapper function ( when an condition is met, it will call that function ), the scrapper is running, but the web controll won't navigate ( looked with fiddler and i'm `debug.writeline` an counter inside the ` while (!finishedLoading)` part, and the counter is raising, but no navigating...

Comment: Any chance you are behind a proxy or something else that is causing the page load to spin endlessly?

Comment: Nope, just at home with no restrictions. But it's only happening when i call the function inside an `DocumentReady event handler` of the `awesomium webcontrol inside the GUI` ( different 1 than the scrapper ( without GUI )...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46702/discussion-between-steve-jansen-and-mathlight)